# Smarty: how to get the same result with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, smarty

example: URL is contained into smarty variable

```
{$image->url|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
```

that is the url field inside the image table. Ok, now in php have the following:

```
echo "<![CDATA[<img src='...' alt='thumb' />";
```

how to replace the content into img src to get the url from database as contained into the smarty variable?

**EDIT**:
i must read the URL field from database inside the image table like smarty does, the result file is .php which shows RSS with xml format

```
echo "\t\t<item>\n";
echo "\t\t\t<title><![CDATA[".$product['name']." - ".html_entity_decode(Tools::displayPrice(Product::getPriceStatic($product['id_product']), $currency), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')." ]]></title>\n";
echo "\t\t\t<pubDate>" . $logged . "</pubDate>\n" ;
```

after that i need the **IMAGE**

Answer (score 0):

that would be something like:

assuming that your php code is something like this:

```
define('_PS_BASE_URL_', 'something');
define('__PS_BASE_URI__', 'something else');
$smarty->assign('image', $image);
```

the tpl file could be **something** like this:

```
<![CDATA[<img src='{Smarty.const._PS_BASE_URL_}{Smarty.const.__PS_BASE_URI__}img/p/{$image.0.id_product}-{$image.0.id_image}-small.jpg' title='{$product.name}' alt='thumb' />
```

read about constants [here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl). also for the name replace you would need to use some [modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl) or [functions](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl)

## Edit 2:

you could use [this modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl) to replace in your text

## Edit 3:

in php just do:

```
echo "<img src='" , htmlentities($image->url, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8') ,  "' />";
```

Comment: maybe is more simple than this, i don't need PS_ etc... infact i edited above...think that's only img src='' don't let you be influenced by the previous src content...

Comment: i must read the url content inside image table and put it into img src...that's it..but with php

Comment: @smepie can you please explain a little more what are you trying to get? from my answer is pretty easy as just remove what you are not going to need.

Comment: "i must read the **url** content _inside_ image **table** and put it into img src...that's it..but with php" is it clear now?

Comment: excuse, i forgot to write that it has to be coded into an xml...before the image there is `echo "\t\t<item>\n";` `echo "\t\t\t<pubDate>" . $logged . "</pubDate>\n" ;`  .... to let you understand